Packaged "External Client App" with Client Credentials Flow, option to select "Run As" user not available in subscriber org
Summary : Subscriber org can not set run as user for client credentials flow after installing a Packaged "External Client App"

I'm developing a 2gp managed package, that includes an "external client app". It will be distributed to clients so that our application can do api communications with their salesforce sales cloud instances.
External Client Apps are relatively new and its a good concept. We developed one, enabled client credentials flow, packaged it and we can successfully install it to a subscriber org.
The problem is, client credentials flow requires a "run as" user. The subscriber org needs to set that under "Manage External Client Apps" page in Setup. And the part of the page that allows that is called "OAuth Flows and External Client App Enhancements" and it is empty, showing : "When you enable flows in this external client app’s settings, they show up here."
Flows are enabled already in the package. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong or if this is a bug.


I am very curious to see if you fixed it, as I have the exact same issue

Hi, i created a ticket with salesforce support, it was acknowledged as a bug. A fix has been released that got into test environment aka sandboxes, and expected to be in production soon. If you have an urgent need, you can also set these using metadata api

Super! This is fantastic news. I will wait for this to be in prod... do you have a link to the bug that I can follow myself?

I insisted several times but they didn't share it with me. I actually thought it wasnt going to get fixed because i didn't have a traceable number but then i saw it fixed in a sandbox. I believe its part of winter 25 release thats being rolled out nowadays

It's fixed now in Winter 25

In Winter 25 this is fixed, I tested it everywhere I had that problem.

Thanks for sharing, i noticed the same!
